# windows phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, hyper-v

To develop windows phone 8.1 app, I Installed VS 2015 professional, windows phone 8.1 SDK tools and emulators but whenever I am running App getting an Error like Windows Phone requires Hyper-V. So I tried to enable Hyper-V but no Hyper-V in Windows turn on or off features and BIOS settings.

Comment: Firstly if you are new develop for WinRT instead as Silverlight is stale. Regarding hyper-v is also dependent on processor and operating system as far as I know. You need windows 8, as minimum. I do not remember the processors unfortunately

Comment: You'll also need a "Pro" or "Enterprise" variant of Windows (8, 8.1 or 10). The "Home" variant does not support Hyper-V

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/q/563023/302